# pass a prop as a string, then convert string back into javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build a reusable carousel that will have much different conditions.

So i need to be able to set this "imageQuery" on my display page, sending it as a string, and then in my carousel, render it as usable javascript

the query works if I just hard code it in, I am just trying to build upon it

My display page has this

```
const imageQuery = 'arts.fineartfields.finehome === "Yes"';
    
<MyCarousel 
  finearts={finearts} 
  imageQuery={imageQuery} 
  />
```

my carousel page has this

```
export default function MyCarousel({ finearts, imageQuery }) {
    
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

    
    
  return (
    <Carousel 
      activeIndex={index} 
      onSelect={handleSelect} 
      className="carousel-fade">

      {finearts.nodes && finearts.nodes.map((arts) => (
        {imageQuery} ?
          <Carousel.Item className="" key={arts.databaseId}>
                            
          <Image src={arts.fineartfields.cloudlink} 
                 alt={arts.featuredImage.node.altText} 
                 className="carousel-image img-fluid shadow-sm"
                 width={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.width}
                 height={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.height}
                 />
          </Carousel.Item>
        : null  
      ), [])}

    </Carousel>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a string? Why not a function that gets passed an `arts` and returns a Boolean? You can pass those as props...

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding, could you show me an example?

Comment: It's just `imageQuery={finehome => finehome === "Yes"}` as the prop and then in the carousel's render: `{imageQuery(arts.fineartfields.finehome)} ? ...`

Comment: `<MyCarousel imageQuery={(arts) => arts.fineartfields.finehome === 'Yes'} ...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass imageQuery props

```
<MyCarousel finearts={finearts} />
```

Carousel component

```
export default function MyCarousel({ finearts }) {
    
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

    
    
  return (
    <Carousel 
      activeIndex={index} 
      onSelect={handleSelect} 
      className="carousel-fade">

      {finearts.nodes && finearts.nodes.map((arts) => (
        arts.fineartfields.finehome === "Yes" ? (
          <Carousel.Item className="" key={arts.databaseId}>
                            
               <Image src={arts.fineartfields.cloudlink} 
                 alt={arts.featuredImage.node.altText} 
                 className="carousel-image img-fluid shadow-sm"
                 width={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.width}
                 height={arts.featuredImage.node.mediaDetails.height}
               />
          </Carousel.Item>
        ) : null  
      ), [])}

    </Carousel>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks again everyone, I like the function idea, but im not sure it will work.. the different strings / condtions I need to send are...   "arts.fineartfields.finehome === "Yes", arts.fineartfields.fineseries === "Figurative", arts.fineartfields.fineseries === "Portraits", arts.fineartfields.fineseries === "Op Art Patterns", etc..

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey I am able to pass the function, but  it is being ignored in my conditional statement

Comment: It works like this.. thanks everyone {finearts.nodes 
        && finearts.nodes.map((arts) => (
        imageQuery(arts) ?

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey  can you post as an answer so I can award you